# Drop down list value doesn't seem to make it into the database for MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm trying to create a drop down list that will let you specify which company an employee works for. Below is my EmployeeViewModel. CompanyId is a foreign-key constrained database field which links to the Company table.

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    public EmployeeViewModel()
    {

    }

    public EmployeeViewModel(Employee Employee, string CompanyName)
    {
        Initialize(Employee, CompanyName);   
    }

    public EmployeeViewModel(Employee Employee, CliFFEntities db)
    {
        Initialize(Employee, db.Companies.Find(Employee.CompanyId).Name);
    }

    private void Initialize(Employee employee, string CompanyName)
    {
        this.Id = employee.Id;
        this.Name = employee.Name;
        this.CompanyId = employee.CompanyId;
        this.InternalId = employee.InternalId;
        this.CompanyName = CompanyName;
    }


    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> InternalId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Company")]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    public String CompanyName { get; set; }

    //public List<Company> CompanyList { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CompanyList { get; set; } //to be set in controller on an as-needed basis
}
```

Relevant part of the Employees controller:

```
    // GET: Employees/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var evm = new EmployeeViewModel();
        evm.CompanyList = new SelectList(db.Companies, "Id", "Name");
        return View(evm);
    }
```

Relevant part of my create view:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CompanyId)
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CompanyId, Model.CompanyList)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CompanyId)
        </div>
    </div>
```

So all that seems to work fine. In fact, when I look at the post data it even sets the CompanyId to the correct value, corresponding to a company ID in the database.

But if I enforce the foreign key on the database side, it throws an error because that CompanyId doesn't seem to make it into the Employee record. If I turn off the FK constraint, the CompanyId just shows up as a 0.

What gives?

Comment: can we see your POST method?

Comment: How are you mapping your view model to the data model? How are you saving your data model? You need to show your POST method

Comment: Thanks, Steves. Apparently I wasn't paying attention to the POST method. I'm super new to MVC! I've posted an answer to my own question.

Answer (score 0):

Welp, looks like I'm so new to MVC 5 that I didn't realize that there's such thing as a post method. Here's what I changed it to to map the EmployeeViewModel back to Employee:

```
   // POST: Employees/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,CompanyId,InternalId")] EmployeeViewModel evm)
    {
        var employee = new Employee { Name = evm.Name, CompanyId = evm.CompanyId, InternalId = evm.InternalId };
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Employees.Add(employee);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(employee);
    }
```

Comment: Remove the awful `BindAttribute` (you never need that when using a view model). And it needs to be `return View(evm);` if `ModelState` is not valid. And you need to reassign the view models `SelectList` property if you returned the view otherwise you would throw an exception

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @StephenMuecke.